# search buttons by id from lightning controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning

I can't get the buttons by seaching with the id from  controller. Below is the code.

## Component

```
<aura:iteration var="qstList" items="{!v.contactList}">
    <!--Listing the contacts-->

     <aura:iteration var="qst" items="{!v.qstLists}" indexVar="index">
            <tbody>

                    {!qst.Title}
                    <button data-index="{!index}" id="{!qstList.Id}"  class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon_border" value="" onclick="{!c.click}">
                    ?
                    </button>
                    <button data-index="{!index}" id="{!qstList.Id}"  class="{!qst.Score=='-1'? 'ButtonP slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border':'slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border'}"
                            value="-1" onclick="{!c.click}">
                    -1
                    </button>
                    <button data-index="{!index}" id="{!qstList.Id}"  class="{!qst.Score=='0'? 'ButtonP slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border':'slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border'}"
                            value="0" onclick="{!c.click}">
                    0
                    </button>
                    <button data-index="{!index}" id="{!qstList.Id}"  class="{!qst.Score=='1'? 'ButtonP slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border':'slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border'}"
                            value="1" onclick="{!c.click}">
                    +1
                    </button>
                    <button data-index="{!index}" id="{!qstList.Id}"  class="{!qst.Score=='2'? 'ButtonP slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border':'slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border'}"
                            value="2" onclick="{!c.click}">
                    +2
                    </button>

            </tbody>
  </aura:iteration>
</aura:iteration>
```

## Controller

```
   init: function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.qstLists", [
        {
            Title: "Question 1",
            Score: null
        },
        {
            Title: "Question 2",
            Score: null
        },
        {
            Title: "Question 3",
            Score: null
        },
        {
            Title: "Question 4",
            Score: null
        },
        {
            Title: "Question 5",
            Score: null
        },
        {
            Title: "Question 6",
            Score: null
        }
    ]);
},

  click: function(component, event, helper) {

    var questions = component.get("v.qstLists");
    var listIndx = component.get("v.contactList");
    var btnId = event.target.id;
   // console.log('btnId-=-=-'+btnId);
    for(var i=0; i<listIndx.length;i++){       
         var index = listIndx[i].Id;
         // console.log('index-->'+index+'  '+'event.target.id -->'+btnId);
        if(index == btnId){
        console.log('Insideindex == event.target.id-->'+index+btnId);
        questions[event.target.dataset.index].Score = event.target.value;
        component.set("v.qstLists", questions);
       }
     }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

SecureComponent#find only finds elements that have a matching aura:id, not a normal id. Further, aura:id doesn't support expression syntax, so you'll have to go about it a different way.

Preferably, you should make a component, like c:question, that displays a single question. This would make your component logic easier to deal with. Alternatively, instead of toggling the classes using $A.util, use an expression to change the class.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.questions}" var="question">
<div id="Q1" class="slds-button-group" role="group">

   <button name="nothing" class="slds-button 
       slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border" 
       data-question-id="{!question.Id}" value="" onclick="{!c.buttonScore}">?
    </button>

   <button name="nothing" class="{!(question.Score__c==-1?'slds-is-selected':'')+'slds-button 
       slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border'}" 
       data-question-id="{!question.Id}" value="-1" onclick="{!c.buttonScore}">-1
    </button>

   <button name="nothing" class="{!(question.Score__c==0?'slds-is-selected':'')+'slds-button 
       slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border'}" 
       data-question-id="{!question.Id}" value="0" onclick="{!c.buttonScore}">0
    </button>

   <button name="nothing" class="{!(question.Score__c==1?'slds-is-selected':'')+'slds-button 
       slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border'}" 
       data-question-id="{!question.Id}" value="1" onclick="{!c.buttonScore}">1
    </button>

   <button name="nothing" class="{!(question.Score__c==2?'slds-is-selected':'')+'slds-button 
       slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border'}" 
       data-question-id="{!question.Id}" value="2" onclick="{!c.buttonScore}">2
    </button>

</div>
```

---

If you use a question component, your questionnaire component would look like this:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.questions}" var="question">
    <c:question question="{!question}" />
</aura:iteration>
```

And the question component itself would contain all of the logic for displaying the question.

---

## Self-Contained Example

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="questions" type="Object[]" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.questions}" var="question" indexVar="index">
        <div>
            {!question.Title}
            <button data-index="{!index}" class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon_border" value="" onclick="{!c.click}">
            ?
            </button>
            <button data-index="{!index}" class="{!join(' ', 'slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon_border ', (question.Score=='-1'?'slds-is-selected':''))}" value="-1" onclick="{!c.click}">
            -1
            </button>
            <button data-index="{!index}" class="{!join(' ', 'slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon_border ', (question.Score=='0'?'slds-is-selected':''))}" value="0" onclick="{!c.click}">
            0
            </button>
            <button data-index="{!index}" class="{!join(' ', 'slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon_border ', (question.Score=='1'?'slds-is-selected':''))}" value="1" onclick="{!c.click}">
            1
            </button>
            <button data-index="{!index}" class="{!join(' ', 'slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon_border ', (question.Score=='2'?'slds-is-selected':''))}" value="2" onclick="{!c.click}">
            2
            </button>
        </div>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:application>
```

## Controller

```
({
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.questions", [
            {
                Title: "Question 1",
                Score: null
            },
            {
                Title: "Question 2",
                Score: null
            },
            {
                Title: "Question 3",
                Score: null
            }
        ]);
    },
    click: function(component, event, helper) {
        var questions = component.get("v.questions");
        questions[event.target.dataset.index].Score = event.target.value;
        component.set("v.questions", questions);
    }
})
```

---

Note: slds-is-selected probably doesn't do what you think it does anyways, so you'll need to try a different SLDS setup, such as the [Radio Button Group](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/radio-button-group/#content), but this should help you get started.

Comment: Thanks.. But I have a list of more than 10+ questions..  Is making components for each of them a good idea ?

Comment: @BijilRavindran I'm writing up a demo. One sec...

Comment: This is very helpful although I don't see how I can put the expression syntax here.. I need to raise these questions separately  from another iterating list of objects which is why I had put id's for each button Eg: "{!'Q1btn'+qstList.Id}" ..

Comment: @BijilRavindran With nested lists, you can use the various indexVar to drill down in to your data.

Comment: Thanks.. I have updated my changed code above..  The button gets selected on click but if I answer to a list of questions for one contact the same gets reflected for all the other contacts. I believe I am setting up the "v.question" attribute at the end of click function wrong. How can I make sure that the question attribute I set is only for the specific contact ? DO I need to make some changes in the init function ?

Comment: @BijilRavindran you need a separate set of scores per contact.